# Cross platform simple program

Tags: linux, windows, macos, installation, cross-platform

Is it possible to write a simple native executable, which can be run in `Windows` `Linux` and `Mac OSX` and the only thing it will do is to check what is the system and run adequate (another) program compiled for this platform?

I want simply to create an installer, which user will download independently of the platform he is using, which will automaticaly discover the platform and unpack (from itself) installer for this particular platform.

Comment: This would be considered a "holy grail" of deployment.  If it were possible it would have been done a _long_ time ago. The fact that it does not exist and there are no products that can truly do this with a single executable file should tell you something.

Comment: @JimGarrison: ELF and PE are mutually incompatible?

Comment: I don't know. Even if they're compatible, the underlying OSes provide different services and different APIs.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I wonder how possible it would be to make a file that looks like both ELF & PE, and has separate bodies of machine code per OS.

Comment: @danilo2 This is simply not possible out of the box, different platforms have different executable file formats different API and different ways of doing things.